# Range.address does not match range.cell[0] address

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, office-interop, officedev

I am developing a VSTO plugin for Excel 2013 using the Office Development Tools for Visual Studio 2012 released in November 2012.

I have a reference to a worksheet and I am trying to access the value of the cells within a range.  This should be a simple task, but for some reason the cell I am trying to access is actually one row higher than the range.  I'm not sure what is causing this or if I am going about this the wrong way.  The following simple example explains the behavior I see.

```
var dataEntrySheet = (Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Worksheets["Data Entry"];
var rangeAddress = dataEntrySheet.Range["A2"].Address
var cellAddress = dataEntrySheet.Range["A2"].Cells[0].Address
```

The results of the above are:

> rangeAddress = "$A$2"
>
> cellAddress = "$A$1"

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of index in here:

```
Cells[0]
```

When accessing rows and columns in excel the indexes start with 1. So 0 actually goes one row up. If you would do:

```
var cellAddress = dataEntrySheet.Range["A1"].Cells[0].Address
```

you would actually get an exception for trying to access a non existing row. You can even use negative indexes to access rows that are further up.